Constant OpenSearch Errors
My error log is absolutely full of these errors, how can I fix it?
Magento ver. 2.4.6-p2
main.CRITICAL: OpenSearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: For input string: "61/"","index":"magento24_product_1_v301","index_uuid":"em82lOqXTkySgFh9YcOwMA"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento24_product_1_v301","node":"7WokmqWuTf6qXlMGpbPeXA","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: For input string: "61/"","index":"magento24_product_1_v301","index_uuid":"em82lOqXTkySgFh9YcOwMA","caused_by":{"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For input string: "61/""}}}]},"status":400} in /var/www/dev/vendor/opensearch-project/opensearch-php/src/OpenSearch/Connections/Connection.php:661
"status":"yellow","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"discovered_master":true,"discovered_cluster_manager":true,"active_primary_shards":7,"active_shards":7,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":3,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":70.0,"indices":{".opensearch-observability":{"status":"green","number_of_shards":1,"number_of_replicas":0,"active_primary_shards":1,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0,"shards":{"0":{"status":"green","primary_active":true,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0}}},".plugins-ml-config":{"status":"green","number_of_shards":1,"number_of_replicas":0,"active_primary_shards":1,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0,"shards":{"0":{"status":"green","primary_active":true,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0}}},".opensearch-sap-log-types-config":{"status":"green","number_of_shards":1,"number_of_replicas":0,"active_primary_shards":1,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0,"shards":{"0":{"status":"green","primary_active":true,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0}}},"magento2_product_1_v9":{"status":"yellow","number_of_shards":1,"number_of_replicas":1,"active_primary_shards":1,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":1,"shards":{"0":{"status":"yellow","primary_active":true,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":1}}},"magento24_product_1_v307":{"status":"yellow","number_of_shards":1,"number_of_replicas":1,"active_primary_shards":1,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":1,"shards":{"0":{"status":"yellow","primary_active":true,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":1}}},".opendistro_security":{"status":"green","number_of_shards":1,"number_of_replicas":0,"active_primary_shards":1,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0,"shards":{"0":{"status":"green","primary_active":true,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0}}},"security-auditlog-2023.10.06":{"status":"yellow","number_of_shards":1,"number_of_replicas":1,"active_primary_shards":1,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":1,"shards":{"0":{"status":"yellow","primary_active":true,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":1}

What happens if you search for numeric only values?
number_format_exception means it cant format the search value to numeric values afaik

@kekw I mean I don't know why it is searching for "61/" instead of just 61 in the first place. Can't Magento deal with a trailing slash?

An issue can happen if you  have more than 85% disk used :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/disk-allocator.html
Check your disk usage with :
df -h

Also you can check the status of the shards here :
http://<yourhost>:9200/_cluster/health/?level=shards


56G   36G   21G free  64% used

have added shard output to original question
